# When do review audits appear?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

Sometimes you encounter audits in the review queues. I know why they exist, but is there any underlying reason for ***when*** they appear?

Comment: If anyone could tell you when, then it would kind of defeat the purpose, no?

Comment: @theB: yes that's true. I didn't think so far...

Comment: They come when you least expect them. MUWAHAHAHAHA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They come at undetermined times for two purposes:

1) They are a test, after all! It needs to be verified that you are actually reading, thinking, and paying attention when looking at the edits. After all, we all want to ensure that the best and most correct winds up on the Stack sites.

2) It helps prevent automation of pushing spam and garbage through the approval process to get it on a highly trafficked site. Could you imagine all of the pharmacy/porn/scam spam that would get posted if there wasn't someone watching the watchers? :D

Comment: Worth noting is that review audits appear more often for new reviewers and reviewers who recently failed audits.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Good point!

Comment: The average on SO is around 2 per 50 reviews under normal conditions but this can be tweaked at will at any moment by a CM.

Comment: By "undetermined times" you mean random, right?